# How can I make SPService webUrl to query a root site from a subsite?

Tags: spservices

I am running SPServices' GetListItems from a subsite (https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/op1/) querying a document library in the root (https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet). This is my SPServices code.

```
$().SPServices(
{
    webUrl         : 'https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/',
    operation      : "GetListItems",
    async          : true,
    listName       : 'Documents',
    CAMLViewFields : "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl'/></ViewFields>",
    // CAMLQuery      : camlQuery,
    completefunc   : function (xData, Status)
        {
            console.log('doclib_getListItems [xData]', xData);
            console.log('doclib_getListItems [Status]', Status);
        }
});
```

However I am getting an error "POST https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/op1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)". I think it is trying to find the "Documents" list in the subsite but not in the site indicated by the webUrl. Is there a way to force SPServices **webUrl** to query the root _vti_bin  (https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists) says the parameter is `webURL`, not `webUrl`.

> GetListItems: [webURL], listName, viewName, CAMLViewFields, CAMLQuery,  CAMLRowLimit, CAMLQueryOptions

Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: this is what happens when one copies code from the internet without double checking.  thank you, it was driving me crazy.